Graph shortest path Dijkstra - time optimisation
So im proceeding through my Algorithm course
Input data
The first line of the input data contains two numbers:  (2≤≤2⋅10^5) and  (1≤≤4⋅10^5) — the number of settlements in the empire and the number of roads in it.
The following  lines describe the roads between the settlements. Each road is described by three numbers: ,  (1≤,,≤,≠) and  (1≤≤10^9). This means that between points with numbers  and  there is a road whose length is .
Output
The first line of the output file must contain one natural number  (2≤≤) — the number of settlements on the shortest path from settlement 1 to settlement .
On the second line, separated by spaces, print the settlements on the shortest path from 1 to  in traversal order, including 1 and  themselves.
If there is no path from 1 to , then output −1. In this case, you may begin to worry about the life of the coachman.
If there are several answers, print any one.
time limit for test: 1 second
Memory limit per test: 256 megabytes
import heapq
import sys

def dijkstra(graph, start, end):
    n = len(graph)
    distances = [float('inf')] * n
    distances[start] = 0
    prev = [-1] * n
    pq = [(0, start)]

    while pq:
        dist, u = heapq.heappop(pq)
        if u == end:
            path = [end]
            while prev[path[-1]] != -1:
                path.append(prev[path[-1]])
            path.reverse()
            return dist, path
        
        for v, w in graph[u]:
            if dist + w < distances[v]:
                distances[v] = dist + w
                prev[v] = u
                heapq.heappush(pq, (distances[v], v))

    return -1, []

#input data
n, m = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
graph = [[] for _ in range(n)]
for _ in range(m):
    v, u, w = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    graph[v-1].append((u-1, w))
    graph[u-1].append((v-1, w))

# Dijkstra func
distance, path = dijkstra(graph, 0, n-1)

# Outout
if distance == -1:
    sys.stdout.write("-1\n")
else:
    sys.stdout.write(str(len(path)) + "\n")
    sys.stdout.write(" ".join(str(x+1) for x in path) + "\n")


The algorithm works right, but I have problems with time limit.
I have already made an optimisation which works x2 faster from the one I have started with, but there are much more optimisation ahead.
I have researched for about 10 days and read already a lot staff on this topic, but either I don't understand how to implement, or its just optimisatiomn
I have chosen Dijkstra algorithm as a classic way to solve this kind of problems.
After researching ways of realizations, I have chosen heap as the fastest recommended.
Also tried another ways to collect the path.
Also changed input output to sys.stdout and have some benefits at speed but still not enough
*
Maybe there is a better algorithm for his task? Or its just the problem of not proper  optimization? *
Input
5 5
1 2 1
2 3 6
3 4 7
4 5 10
1 4 3
1 3 4
Output 3
1 4 5
Input
8 9
1 2 4
2 3 6
3 1 5
1 4 5
1 5 5
5 4 7
5 6 1
6 7 1
7 8 1
Output
5
1 5 6 7 8
Input
5 4
1 2 5
1 3 5
2 3 1
4 5 1
Output

Sure
Input
5 5
1 2 1
2 3 6
3 4 7
4 5 10
1 4 3
1 3 4
Output
3
1 4 5
Input
8 9
1 2 4
2 3 6
3 1 5
1 4 5
1 5 5
5 4 7
5 6 1
6 7 1
7 8 1
Output
5
1 5 6 7 8
Input
5 4
1 2 5
1 3 5
2 3 1
4 5 1
Output
-1

That's all tests that are not hidden
However, they all pass well except time limits

Maybe I should better use A*?
but as far as I have read its more suitable for avoiding obstacles

@KarLa It may be the one second time limit. That should be like 3-4 seconds. Other folks python's solutions passes? Try C++. Might pass. Python is slower.

@KarlLa Check out fibheap to see if allowed. Use it and see. Slightly faster. But still not much. Ideone

Ok
I added the data to the question

And also have pushed speed a bit forward

No, the task is on university and testing system is private

As far as I can see I should use another algorithm,
but first want to try it in Cpp

It would help if you could add code that generates a worst case graph.

Ok I have some news
I found a task on Codeforce https://codeforces.com/contest/20/problem/C
And my solution is totally fine! All tests passed, all in time!

So it should not be Dijkstra for the original task I try to solve

The one on Codeforce is fine, but the same solution for my task - fails in speed

the one on code force works with input 10^6  and my with 10^9

Did you try submitting with C++?

Yes, not much faster

after dist, u = heapq.heappop(pq), do if dist != distances[u]: continue

Still overusage of time

As we don't have anything to test with, this is going to be a shot in the dark, but you could get some runtime gain if you use a bidirectional Dijkstra search.
Here is a possible implementation of that idea:
from heapq import heappop, heappush
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ShortestPath:
    distance = float("inf")
    node_on_path = None
        

class DijkstraState:
    def __init__(self, graph, start, shortest: ShortestPath):
        n = len(graph)
        self.graph = graph
        self.distances = [float('inf')] * n
        self.distances[start] = 0
        self.prev = [-1] * n
        self.pq = [(0, start)]
        self.opposite_distances = []
        self.shortest = shortest
        
    def process_next(self):
        dist, node = heappop(self.pq)
        if dist == self.distances[node]:
            for neighbor, weight in self.graph[node]:
                neighbor_dist = dist + weight
                if neighbor_dist < self.distances[neighbor]:
                    self.distances[neighbor] = neighbor_dist
                    self.prev[neighbor] = node
                    heappush(self.pq, (neighbor_dist, neighbor))
                    total_distance = neighbor_dist + self.opposite_distances[neighbor]
                    if total_distance < self.shortest.distance:
                        self.shortest.distance = total_distance
                        self.shortest.node_on_path = neighbor
        return dist

    def get_path_to_start(self):
        node = self.shortest.node_on_path
        while node != -1:
            yield node
            node = self.prev[node]


def dijkstra(graph, start, end):
    if start == end:  # Boundary case
        return [start]
    shortest = ShortestPath()  # mutable object to record shortest of inspected paths
    forward = DijkstraState(graph, start, shortest)
    backward = DijkstraState(graph, end, shortest)
    # Each gets a reference to the distances found in the other direction
    forward.opposite_distances = backward.distances
    backward.opposite_distances = forward.distances
    
    while forward.pq and backward.pq:
        distance = forward.process_next() + backward.process_next()
        if distance >= shortest.distance:  # Sure to have found the shortest path
            path = list(forward.get_path_to_start())[:0:-1]
            path.extend(backward.get_path_to_start())
            return path

NB: as you can see this doesn't return the distance. I don't think you need it. To know when to output -1 it suffices to check whether None was returned:
# ... 
# ...

# Dijkstra func
path = dijkstra(graph, 0, n-1)

# Outout
if not path:
    print("-1")
else:
    print(len(path))
    print(" ".join(str(x+1) for x in path))

